# Android studio rendering: null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.isThemeAppCompat(RenderSessionImpl.java:1201)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.findStatusBar(RenderSessionImpl.java:1063)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:206)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:319)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:646)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:584)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Another activity uses the same theme and works fine in the renderer. The theme is based on Theme.AppCompat.Light if that helps. I replaced the file with the exact same XML and it worked fine but the editor claimed it could not find it and started flashing everywhere. After a restart it had the same issue.

I have spent hours trying to figure this out and have found nothing. Please help me.

Comment: At least a lead, please!

Comment: I'm having the same issue using this site: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator

Answer (score 28):

[image]

Change the theme in the xml viewer in Android Studio

Comment: Image in answer is dead. *(403. That’s an error. Your client does not have permission to get URL /xaTj0AM_n92Fu6XEfsGecAE_MCwEeoAS7bylNtn3qD_-D2UXz5M5PPArlZqa4IxVr9JQrL_Yf6wuwzA=w1399-h1005 from this server... Forbidden That’s all we know.)*

Comment: Man, I've already accepted these sort of bugs from this IDE as a given fact... Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I've changed theme in xml descriptor trying to find out solution for another bug, and didn't figure out that after changing theme back, Idea was remember theme selection in designer and throwed that exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with you using a theme that is not supported.

For example, holo.light is a theme that Android Lollipop doesn't recognize. Consider replacing it with material.light.

This was at least the issue for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using Theme.appcompact.Light.DarkactionBar. I remade the entire app in another project. Literally the same code and it works fine. I just lost alot of time.